# Rails - path to font does work on production, but doesn't on localhost

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fonts, font-face

Here's the CSS block where I load CSS fonts:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueRegular';
    src: url('../fonts/helveticaneue/helveticaneue-roman.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/helveticaneue/helveticaneue-roman.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/helveticaneue/helveticaneue-roman.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/helveticaneue/helveticaneue-roman.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/helveticaneue/helveticaneue-roman.svg#helvetica_neueregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The fonts are located in `/app/assets/fonts` directory.

On the localhost, when I load the page, the fonts are not loaded, but on Heroku are all fonts loaded correctly.

What is wrong?

Comment: You probably need to use the `asset_path` helper. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-erb

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are seeing this, is that in a production environment all the assets are compiled and put into a single folder `/assets/asset-name`. With that said, both css and type faces are in the same folder, and can be accessed via the relative path. In a development environment, assets are not compiled and can be accessed at `/assets/asset-type/asset-name`, which means that the CSS and type faces won't be in the same folder.

To overcome this obstacle, Rails has an amazing helper called [asset-url](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets).

So for your example:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'HelveticaNeueRegular';
src: asset-url('helveticaneue-roman.eot');
src: asset-url('helveticaneue-roman.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     asset-url('helveticaneue/helveticaneue-roman.woff') format('woff'),
     asset-url('helveticaneue/helveticaneue-roman.ttf') format('truetype'),
     asset-url('helveticaneue/helveticaneue-roman.svg#helvetica_neueregular')     format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Plus, since you added a fonts folder under assets, you will need to add this to your asset path: `config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"` in the `config/application.rb`

Comment: I don't understand it, but I tried to use `asset-url` helper and when I load the page, I don't get any error, but on the page are not used these fonts... Damn!

Comment: Are you saying that you are not getting any errors, and the type face isn't being used?

Comment: Exactly. There are no errors in JS console neither in the Rails log file.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the way the asset pipeline works:

- In development environment, all assets are serverd dynamically from `/app/assets/...`.
- In production environment, assets are compiled and *moved* to `/public/assets/` from where a web server can pickup the now static files.

I suspect the paths in your `fonts.css` (accidently?) point to the files in production environment.

To solve your situation, you basically have two options:

1. move the font files into your `/public` directory (e.g. `/public/fonts`) and reference the files from there:

   ```
   @font-face {
     font-family: 'HelveticaNeueRegular';
     src: url('/fonts/helveticaneue/helveticaneue-roman.eot');
     src: url('/fonts/helveticaneue/helveticaneue-roman.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
          url('/fonts/helveticaneue/helveticaneue-roman.woff') format('woff'),
          url('/fonts/helveticaneue/helveticaneue-roman.ttf') format('truetype'),
          url('/fonts/helveticaneue/helveticaneue-roman.svg#helvetica_neueregular') format('svg');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
   }
   ```
2. Use Rails' Asset helpers. A good introduction can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out this issue - into `config/application.rb` add following:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

Comment: Ahh! Yes, that makes since, because you added a fonts folder under assets. So it needed to be added to the assets path. I will add this to my answer as well.

Comment: Other than initially forgetting to set the assets path, did I answer your question?